# Necessity of filling Form 1116 or Form 2555

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-1040, resident

I left the USA in February 2019, pass the substantial presence test for 2019, and am filing my US taxes as resident alien. Just on my US sourced income, I do not owe any taxes and don't need any foreign tax credit. So do I need to file 1116 or 2555 and attach it with 1040 at all given that I had Indian income later in the year, and that I paid taxes on it?

Comment: Have you considered the option of using the [Last Year of Residency](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2019_publink1000222182) rules to make yourself resident only until you left the US, and nonresident after (so you would be a dual-status alien for 2019)?

Comment: @user102008 There is no standard deduction for this option, and it's more complicated to exercise.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to consider just US source income since I am filing as non-resident. I need to consider my global income, and there will most likely be a non-zero tax on it against which I can claim a foreign tax credit corresponding to the tax that I have paid elsewhere.